What should I use as preposition ? "Of" or "About"
"His knowledge of politics is enormous"
Above sentence can be written as "His knowledge about politics is enormous"
Is there any difference? where should I put "of" and where should I put "about"?
Are both grammatically correct?
Does meaning differ?

This Ngram shows that knowledge of is much more usual than knowledge about, though the distance between them is narrowing. Both are grammatically correct and mean the same.
We usually say that someone has knowledge of a broad subject such as politics, geography etc. and that they know about a particular fact or circumstance - but this isn't a strict rule.
